# How to downgrade if version is not known?

Tags: apt, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade libboost-dev-all from 1.58 to  1.55.0.1.  However if I do apt-cache showpkg libboost-dev-all it doesnt show 1.55.0.1 as a version to select.

Whats the cleanest way to install 1.55.0.1 with all dependencies and lock it so it wont get updated?

Thanks!

Comment: it is in the `trusty` (16.04) repo. there are 28 depends.

Comment: okay so I put trusty into sources.list and now I could install with libboost-all-dev=1.54.0.1ubuntu1  BUT it still shows the dependencies of 1.58. Is that correct? I probably wand the 1.54 dependencies right?

Comment: Warning: Downgrading is possible but unsupported. It's dangerous, and can break your system in quite horrible ways if you are not proficient with dpkg, apt, and the Ubuntu repositories. If your system breaks, the best advice you will receive is to undo your work and return to a supported version of Ubuntu. Your question indicates that you might be entering dangerous territory unprepared.